# How to autosize the very first columns width in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, autosize

I am using the below code to let text in all columns of the datagrid to be fitted nicely.

It works but not for the VERY FIRST column in the datagrid which is the "number" column. That column does not change and stays the same size. In that column I have  increasing numbers only.

How to make the Very First column in the datagrid to autosize in width to fit the numbers exactly?

```
void resizeandfitgridcolumns(DataGridView dgv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        dgv.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        int colw = dgv.Columns[i].Width;
        dgv.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
        dgv.Columns[i].Width = colw;
    }
    dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you needed to write your own class for the very first column like below:

```js
public class CustomHeaderCell : DataGridViewRowHeaderCell
{
    protected override Size GetPreferredSize(Graphics graphics, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, int rowIndex, Size constraintSize)
    {
        var size1 = base.GetPreferredSize(graphics, cellStyle, rowIndex, constraintSize);
        var value = string.Format("{0}", this.DataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].HeaderCell.FormattedValue);
        var size2 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(value, cellStyle.Font);
        var padding = cellStyle.Padding;
        return new Size(size2.Width + padding.Left+padding.Right, size1.Height);
    }
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts.Background);
        base.PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, string.Format("{0}", formattedValue), cellStyle.Font, cellBounds, cellStyle.ForeColor);
    }
}
```

Then it's enough to replace current header cells with your new header cell:

```js
//Put this lines before adding rows
grid.RowTemplate.DefaultHeaderCellType = typeof(CustomHeaderCell);
grid.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders;
grid.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(2);
```